# Disposing of controls in a layout at runtime on android application

Tags: android, controls, widget, runtime

I need to reset a layout or dispose some of the controls on that layout according to some certain cases. But I couldn't find a way to do so. Do you have an idea about how to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I write the below code when needed, isn't the layout supposed to be zeroed? 


`linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can just the hide the components, e.g. `findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_view_to_hide).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

There are different parameters for the visibility. `GONE` hides the view and also frees up the space, the view used before, as if it was removed completely.

Comment: Thanks henrik. What you said serves the purpose. But I can't reach and dispose a linearlayout that resides in a viewflipper by this way. Is there a way to do so?