# How to free the memory of a Layout and all his children views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some huge layouts which I need to free from the memory in some cases, and these layouts have a lot of children.

Which is the best way to achieve it?

I can't find the way on Google.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686671/disposing-of-controls-in-a-layout-at-runtime-on-android-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign  id to your  layout, get a reference to it and call  `removeAllViews();` to remove all its child view. If l1 is  my LinearLayout, then  `l1. removeAllViews();`

Comment: it removes the views, but somehow doesn't free up the memory. I need to restart my app to get it working.